# Finding Files With a Particular Pattern

Tags: linux, grep, find

I want to find files which have abc in its name.

For example:

Dozain123.ctabcln_WbLogReq.log'

Dozain123.ctabcln_WbLogReq123.log

Dozain123.ctabcln_WbLogReq456.log

Dozain123.ctabcln_WbLogReq341.log

Which command should I use?

Comment: You want to find only the filenames, not their location?

Comment: yes, when I do ls I get a bunch of files , I want to find the ones having "abc" in it

Answer (score 3):

If it's files in the *current directory* that you want to list:

```
ls ./*abc*
```

To loop over these files:

```
for fname in ./*abc*; do
    # do something with "$fname"
done
```

If you want to find them in the current directory or anywhere in some subdirectory (recursively):

```
find . -type f -name '*abc*' -print
```

(this assumes that all names that you want to find are names of regular files, i.e. not names of directories etc.)

If you want to do something with *these* names:

```
find . -type f -name '*abc*' -exec sh -c '
    for fname do
        # do something with "$fname" here
    done' sh {} +
```

Using the `**` globbing pattern available in some shells (by default in `zsh` and with `shopt -s globstar` in `bash`) to do a recusive matching of filenames:

```bash
for fname in ./**/*abc*; do
    # do something with "$fname"
done
```

With the `zsh` shell, also making sure that we only match names of regular files (i.e. not directories etc.):

```sh
for fname in ./**/*abc*(.); do
    # do something with "$fname"
done
```

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Answer (score -1):

if you want to find all abc name in file:
$ grep -R abc ./Direction

or if you want to find file who contain abc:
$ ls -1 | grep abc
 or
$ ls *abc* ./Direction

Comment: This is not about matching the _contents_ of files, but filenames.